# Django: Save data in a Table but at the same time edit or modify data from a different table

Tags: python, django

#I am trying to save data in the constancia_pro table but at the same time I want to edit or modify the status field from "NO" to "YES" of the lpro_reg table when I save it, but it generates this error: The lpro_reg could not be changed because the data didn't validate.#

```
models.py 

`class lpro_reg(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  tipodoc = (
      ('V', 'V'),
      ('E', 'E'),
      ('J', 'J'),
      ('G', 'G'),
    )
   tipo = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipodoc, default='J')
   documento= models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
   presentante = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
   fecha_reg= models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   ramos = models.ManyToManyField(ciuu)
   direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
   n_recibo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
   fecha_recibo = models.DateField()
   fecha_apert = models.DateField()
   opciones = (
      ('SI', 'SI'),
      ('NO', 'NO'),
   )
   status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=opciones, default='NO')
   responsable = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
      db_table = 'prov_reg'
      ordering = ['id']

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)

class constancia_pro(models.Model):
   licencia2 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   n_constanica = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
   aprobado = models.OneToOneField(lpro_reg, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   fecha_reg = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'pro_const'
       ordering = ['-licencia2']

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.licencia2)`

views.py 

`verdatos = get_object_or_404(lpro_reg.objects, pk = id)
ultimodato = constancia_pro.objects.first()
ultima_id = int(ultimodato.n_constanica)`

`if request.method == 'POST':
    
    formulario = aprobado_form(request.POST)
    formulario2 = registroprovicional_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=verdatos)
    

    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.instance.n_constanica = ultima_id + 1
        formulario.instance.aprobado = lpro_reg.objects.filter(pk = id).first()`
        formulario2.instance.status = 'SI'
        formulario2.save()
        formulario.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Se ha guardado correctamente')
        return redirect('/actividad_economica/')


return render(request, 'act_econ/aprobacion.html', {'info':verdatos})
```

`

I expected the status field to change from NO to YES when I hit the approve or save button.

Answer (score 0):

**You are going to save two form. So, check validation for both form(is_valid()).Otherwise , data could not be validate.**

```
if formulario.is_valid() and formulario2.is_valid():
            formulario.instance.n_constanica = ultima_id + 1
            formulario.instance.aprobado = lpro_reg.objects.filter(pk = id).first()`
            formulario2.instance.status = 'SI'
            formulario2.save()
            formulario.save()
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, although the error doesn't appear anymore, it is not saving the data, the problem must be with form 2 that is not editing the status field.

Comment: One more thing formulario.instance.n_constanica(where is that instance variable come from).I haven't seen it above in your code.May be check it again.

Comment: the n_contancia comes from the contancia_pro table, that field is auto-incremented by taking the value of the last save and adding one each time I save in the constancia_pro table, but as I told you, the problem has to be form2 since if I remove the code from form2 it saves form 1.

Comment: Done, I managed to solve the problem by removing all the code from form2 and putting this code lpro_reg.objects.filter(pk = id).update(status = 'YES')

Comment: Okey.That's Great.